# Robocopy copies folders but not files

Tags: windows, copy, robocopy

I'm using `robocopy` on a Windows Server 2008 R2 SP2 machine with the following options:

```
robocopy W:\ E:\old_files\daten1\ /R:1 /W:1 /MIR /COPYALL /ZB /DCOPY:T /MT 50 /LOG:E:\old_files\copy_w.txt
```

`robocopy` copies all of the folders, but at the destination they appear empty without the files. I cannot find any errors in the log file. Security permissions are OK.

Comment: Suggest trying repeatedly dropping one option at a time until you get the files copied. This will give you the option that is causing the problem, then build back up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If that is the command line you're using then your problem is most likely the `/MT 50`. I suspect you meant `/MT:50` to have 50 threads rather than files called 50.

Comment: missing : was the problem